# Why get error 404 when I try to pass date variable in get request to web api method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I work on my web api project.
I get error 404 when I try to pass date variable in get request to web api method.

Here is web api method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ReportDetailed/{clientId}/{date}")]
public IHttpActionResult ReportDetailed(int clientId, DateTime date )
{
    return Ok();
}
```

And here how I try to access to the function above(row from URL):

`http://localhost/station/api/Reports/ReportDetailed/12/Wed%20Jun%2001%202016%2000:00:00%20GMT+0300%20(Jerusalem%20Daylight%20Time)`

where clientId is 12 and date is parsed javascript date object:

```
/Wed%20Jun%2001%202016%2000:00:00%20GMT+0300%20(Jerusalem%20Daylight%20Time)
```

when I remove from URL above the parsed Date object and date parameter from web api function it works perfect (so I guess the problem with date object).

Any idea why I get error 404 when I try to pass object in URI?

Comment: What if you try a more simplified date, eg: `/ReportDetailed/12/2016-06-06`?  Does that work?  If so, it's the model binder for date not recognising your date - you could use a string param and parse it in your action (throwing an exception if you can't parse it)

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you. Your  comment helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provided date is not in a valid date format. Try a more universally parse-able format like `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` for example.

You should also use [Route constraints](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints) on your parameters which will try to validate your parameters to make sure they are in the correct format

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("ReportDetailed/{clientId:int}/{date:datetime}")]
public IHttpActionResult ReportDetailed(int clientId, DateTime date )
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Date format is not recognizable by .NET
First convert your date to UTC string, this will return a string representation of your date. So the value will be passes as string

```
var dateString= dateJs.toUTCString();
```

Then in your C# code parse it.

```
public IHttpActionResult ReportDetailed(int clientId, string dateString)
    DateTime dateC# = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

Comment: Katana, when I try to parse toUTCString() I get wrong date: "Tue, 31 May 2016 21:00:00 GMT"

Comment: @Michael I think you are creating a new date instance. Use the value you pasted above.
Michael is the error in the API gone?

Comment: @Michael sorry i forgot to mention that the output of toUTCString is a string so need to change your datetime parameter in API to string

Comment: I use  toISOString()

Comment: I get date undefined in the action

Comment: @Michael is this ok now?

Comment: @Katana if a new data instance gives 31May on 06June, there's something else seriously wrong... :)

Comment: @Michael i think you can figure it out, just update if you cannot :) Is the action reachable now?